# Parallel.Foreach is to0 slow. How can I optimize my code

Tags: c#, optimization, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have the flollowing code that takes more than 7 minutes to complete, even when I use Parallel.Foreach. The list "final_products" that I iterate over contains about 7000 products.

```
 public void GenerateTreeFromAllFinalProducts()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImageFeature<float>[]));
        DSTableAdapters.Products_UniqueTableAdapter pft = new DSTableAdapters.Products_UniqueTableAdapter();
        DSTableAdapters.Products_Unique_SURFTableAdapter pus = new DSTableAdapters.Products_Unique_SURFTableAdapter();
        DS.Products_UniqueDataTable final_products = pft.GetData();

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        Parallel.ForEach(final_products.AsParallel(), row =>
        {                 
            //Get SURF data for all images found similar to this image
            Types.Products_Unique_SURFRow surfData = GetDataByUniqueProductID(row.id);

            ImageFeature<float>[] row_features = (ImageFeature<float>[])serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(Decompress(surfData.SURF)));
            if (row_features != null)
                flann.AddSurfDescriptors(row_features, row.id);                       
        });

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
```

Is this normalt that it takes this long and if not how can I optimize the code?

GetDataByUniqueProductID(row.id) is a call to my Database that returns 1 single row.

```
private static Types.Products_Unique_SURFRow GetDataByUniqueProductID(int rowid)
    {
        Types.Products_Unique_SURFRow ret = new Types.Products_Unique_SURFRow();

        string sqlText = "SET ROWCOUNT 1 SELECT SURF from Products_Unique_SURF WHERE unique_product_id =" + rowid;

        using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(global::SCBot.Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString))
        {
            myConn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, myConn);
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Types.Products_Unique_SURFRow row = new Types.Products_Unique_SURFRow();
                    row.SURF = Convert.ToString(reader["SURF"]);

                    ret = row;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

My initial code was the following

```
 public void GenerateTreeFromAllFinalProducts()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImageFeature<float>[]));
        DSTableAdapters.Products_UniqueTableAdapter pft = new DSTableAdapters.Products_UniqueTableAdapter();
        DSTableAdapters.Products_Unique_SURFTableAdapter pus = new DSTableAdapters.Products_Unique_SURFTableAdapter();
        DS.Products_UniqueDataTable final_products = pft.GetData();

        foreach (DS.Products_UniqueRow row in final_products)
        {
            //Get SURF data for all images found similar to this image
            List<DS.Products_Unique_SURFRow> surfData = pus.GetDataByUniqueProductID(row.id).ToList();

            foreach (DS.Products_Unique_SURFRow data in surfData)
            {
                ImageFeature<float>[] row_features = (ImageFeature<float>[])serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(Decompress(data.SURF)));
                flann.AddSurfDescriptors(row_features, row.id);
            }
        }
    }
```

But this was too slow, that is why I tried to do a Parallel.Foreach

Answer (score 0):

You should measure the time the inner code takes. Parallel won't speed-up the inner code. Instead of nesting the methods Decompress/Deserialize, you could measure them separately.

After edit:

Each thread will create a new connection. I think this is as great example how **not** to use parallel as speeding up. But changing the algoritme will help more. Because querying single rows on different connections/threads wll cost more time than query them all (or a selection) and single threaded foreach loop them.

My view:

I would collect all id's of the final_products enemration and buildup a string using a stringbuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuiler();
bool isFirst = true;

sb.Append("(");
foreach(var prod in final_products)
{
    if(isFirst)
        isFirst = false;
    else
        sb.Append(", ");

    sb.Append(prod.Id);
}
sb.Append(")");

string query = "SELECT SURF FROM Products_Unique_SURF WHERE Id in "+sb.ToString();

// execute the query

// foreach row, decompress, deserialize etc...
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that I should try to get the entire list of SURF-data in one query and then run parellel on that?

Comment: I don't think you need Parallel, because most of the time your code is connecting/querying data. I don't think the Decompress/Deserialize is very slow. If the Decompress/Deserialize is slow, you could use parallel on that, but you should try to avoid querying single rows.

Comment: You are correct, the Decompress/Deserialize is not slow. What takes time is iterating 7000 products and getting the single SURF-row.

Comment: I have tried to get the entire Products_Unique_SURF, but SURF data is very large and it therefore takes more than 1 hour to get the entire table. That is why I am trying to get 1 single row at a time. If i try to get the data as "Jeroen van Langen" says, this would take to much time, since the data is to large.

Comment: I don't think it will take more time than splitting queries up to single rows. The 1 hour run is the initial code you said? It looks like a master detail. Why not sub query the data? _SELECT Id, (SELECT TOP 1 SURF FROM Products_Unique_SURF Child WHERE Child.unique_product_id = Parent.Id) AS SURF FROM Products_Unique Parent_     (PSEUDO/NOT TESTED)

Comment: the 1 hour is when i try to run the query Select * From Products_Unique_SURF, and actually my machine runs out of memory. What I am trying to state is that table contains large data, since the SURF column is a very long string. The idea behind Select * From Products_Unique_SURF was to hold the entire table in a list and iterate over that. I thought that might be faster than getting one row at a time.

Comment: Does it make any difference that I am running a localDB with an mdf file than using a actual database?

Comment: Depends on the hardware. For my info, how many ImageFeature<floats> are in 1 SURF field? Is there another way to store them? (files) Do you need all 7000 rows at ones?

Comment: I have an image that I need to compare with all 7000 images, and this is done by comparing the SURF. There 1 ImageFeature for each SURF. I can store the data on server instead of having an mdf file, but I wanted to be sure that it would make a difference before I use the time to do it.